# Is disconnectedness local?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $F$ is a closed set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>1$ and $V$ an open set that contains $F$. It seems correct that if $V\setminus F$ is disconnected, then $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F$ is also disconnected. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****Counterexample:**** $F=\{0\}$ and $V=B((0,0),1)\cup B((500, 0), 1)$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Here $B$ is an open ball in the Euclidean metric.

Comment: It's a bit of a cop-out when $V$ is already disconnected. I think this should be true when $V$ is connected, but it might be difficult.

Comment: I think as well that it becomes true once we assume that $V$ is connected. As $V\setminus F$ and $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F$ are open, being connected is equivalent to being path-connected. So essentially it boils down to showing that we can alter the path s.t. it stays inside of $V$. However, $F$ is closed and $V$ is open, so there is some space to wiggle.